# Phoenix emits "protocol Enumerable not implemented" error when path helpers get called

Tags: phoenix-framework

For a Phoenix app, I created two routes as following:

```
scope "/", Greeter do
  pipe_through :browser

  get "/hello", HelloController, :show
  get "/hello/:name", HelloController, :show
end
```

With them, the app can respond to the both "/hello" and "/hello/alice" paths.

But, when I use the path helper `hello_path(@conn, :show, "alice")` to produce "/hello/alice", Phoenix server emits this error message:

> protocol Enumerable not implemented for "alice"

The cause is simple.

The first route creates two helpers `hello_path/2` and `hello_path/3`, but the second route creates only one helper `hello_path/4` because the `hello_path/3` is already defined.

This `hello_path/3` demands an *enumerable* as the third argument.

How should I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give one of the route a different name using `as:`:

```
get "/hello", HelloController, :show
get "/hello/:name", HelloController, :show, as: :hello_with_name
```

Test:

```
iex(1)> import MyApp.Router.Helpers
MyApp.Router.Helpers
iex(2)> hello_path MyApp.Endpoint, :show
"/hello"
iex(3)> hello_path MyApp.Endpoint, :show, foo: "bar"
"/hello?foo=bar"
iex(4)> hello_with_name_path MyApp.Endpoint, :show, "alice"
"/hello/alice"
iex(5)> hello_with_name_path MyApp.Endpoint, :show, "alice", foo: "bar"
"/hello/alice?foo=bar"
```